# Convergence of this series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \ln\frac{\cosh\frac{1}{n}}{\cos\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'd like to know convergence of  this series

> $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \ln\frac{\cosh\frac{1}{n}}{\cos\frac{1}{n}}$$

but  I can not guess what test can be useful. I wounder if anybody here could give me hints?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By expanding the functions
$$
\ln \frac{\cosh {\frac 1n}}{\cos \frac 1n} = \ln \frac{1 + \frac{1}{2n^2} + o\left(\frac 1{n^2}\right)}{1 - \frac{1}{2n^2} + + o\left(\frac 1{n^2}\right)} = \ln \left({1 + \frac{1}{n^2} + o\left(\frac 1{n^2}\right)}\right) = \frac {1}{n^2} + o\left(\frac 1{n^2}\right),
$$
the series is easily seen as convergent.

Comment: @ Dear Wang Songbo,very nice answer,thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. We may start from the Weierstrass products:
$$ \cos(x) = \prod_{m\geq 0}\left(1-\frac{4x^2}{(2m+1)^2\pi^2}\right), \qquad \cosh(x) = \prod_{m\geq 0}\left(1+\frac{4x^2}{(2m+1)^2\pi^2}\right)$$
to get:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\log\frac{\cosh\frac{1}{n}}{\cos\frac{1}{n}}=2\sum_{m\geq 0}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\text{arctanh}\left(\frac{4}{n^2(2m+1)^2 \pi^2}\right) $$
and:

> $$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{n\geq 1}\log\frac{\cosh\frac{1}{n}}{\cos\frac{1}{n}} &=& 2\sum_{m\geq 0}\sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{h\geq 0}\frac{1}{2h+1}\left(\frac{4}{n^2(2m+1)^2 \pi^2}\right)^{2h+1}\\&=&\color{red}{2\sum_{h\geq 0}\frac{4^{2h+1}-1}{(2h+1)\,\pi^{4h+2}}\, \zeta(4h+2)^2}\end{eqnarray*}$$

that is a fast convergent series, since $\frac{4}{\pi^2}$ is way smaller than one and $\zeta(4h+2)\to 1$ quite fast as $h\to +\infty$.